# Can Org-Babel code be converted to Elisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have an org-babel source, which accesses a server via tramp and runs a shell script there. Is it possible to convert this source block into an Elisp function?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir "/pscp:putty-connection-xy:/dir-yz" 
expect -c '
spawn bash -c  "scp file-to-copy user@server:/home1/dir-xy"
expect {
    "(yes/no)?" {
        send "yes\r"
        expect "*?assword:*"
        send "secretPassWord\r"
    }
    "*?assword:*" {
        send "secretPassWord\r"
    }
}
expect eof
'
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tramp's multi-hop (untested):

```
(copy-file "/plink:putty-connection-xy:/dir-yz/file-to-copy"
           "/plink:putty-connection-xy|ssh:user@server:/home1/dir-xy/")
```

This uses `plink` and `ssh`, 'tho. If you can connect `user@server` directly from your local machine, you could shorten this, using `pscp`:

```
(copy-file "/pscp:putty-connection-xy:/dir-yz/file-to-copy"
           "/pscp:user@server:/home1/dir-xy/")
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I was looking for a solution to convert this code into an Elisp function. Due to the permission I have to enter the password.

Comment: Passwords could be handled by the `auth-source` package.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. I call the block and give it over
'sh', the code and the parameters of the block. It works

```
(org-babel-execute-src-block nil 
'("sh" 
   "cd /home1/
    expect -c '    
spawn bash -c \"scp file-to-copy user@server:/home1/dir-xy .\"
     expect { 
             \"*?assword:*\" {           
   send \"secretPassWord\\r\"        }    }   
   expect eof'
   " 
  ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) 
   (:result-params "raw" "replace") 
   (:result-type . value) (:results . "silent") 
   (:exports . "code") 
   (:tangle . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") 
   (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil nil ))
```